# Checking equality of 2 mathematical expressions using Python

Tags: python, math, formula, physics

I am making a program which asks the user a mathematical formula from physics and the user has to tell the answer. So the bot might ask "Tell me the first equation of motion in terms of V where U is initial velocity, A is acceleration, T is time" and the user must answer V = U + A * T. Now the problem arises when the user may enter A * T + U or U + T * A. Also, since subtraction and division are sensitive to order, it will not work. Is there any way to implement this logic.

I tried segregating the terms using split function on + and then making a nested list of seperation using *. So the expected answer is in terms of lists and nested lists. But then again, subtraction cannot be represented in this form. In theory, U + A * T will be converted to

```
[[U], [A, T]]
```

but if the answer were some X * (A + B), it will not function as intended.

Comment: What can a user enter? Complete formula like `V = U + A * T` and `U = V - A * T` along with all the variants of these formulas??

Comment: No, as it is specified by the bot, it is in terms of V, so it has to be V = something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing equivalence of mathematical expressions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154954/testing-equivalence-of-mathematical-expressions-in-python)

Comment: I'm sorry but that problem is different and relates more towards the variables from the set around the operation rather than the operation itself

Comment: You can use sympy. See e.g. [Sympy - Comparing expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112738/sympy-comparing-expressions). Just be carefull not to use `==` on sympy expressions, but `Eq` or subtracting and comparing to zero.

Comment: The problem with sympy is its related to operations on variable, whereas my inputs are all strings

Comment: `>>> import sympy; >>> sympy.sympify('U + A * T') == sympy.sympify('A * T + U')`
gives `True`. No problem with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some test cases:

Like for V=U+A*T let say in test case 1[4,2,5] where U is 4, A is 2 and T is 5, then compare by calculating the value of your V with the user's formula V if all the test case passed the formula is correct.

Comment: This method may or may not work for some test cases, like if the user enters an equation which leads to the same answer, but is wrong

Comment: you can improve it passing the value through multiple testcases

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much